# Remap ':w' in VScode Vim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

[image: ']

I'm trying to remap ':w' to 'zz' in vscode vim. I've made 2 attempts, (one commented out). So far its not working. How can I perform this remap?

```
"vim.commandLineModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": [":","w"],
        "after": ["z", "z"]
        // "before": ["z", "z"],
        // "after": [":","w"]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following to map `zz` to the `save` action:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["z", "z"],
        "commands": [
            ":w"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thats cool ! - I should be able to award you bounty within 24 hours. It won't let me do it yet ..